# Dependency Injection in IAuthorizationFilter ASP.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I create a filter `IAuthorizationFilter` and I need to use DepencyInjection in this attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AllowAccessAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IDomainUnitOfWork unitofwork;
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;

    public AllowAccessAttribute(IDomainUnitOfWork unitofwork,HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        this.unitofwork = unitofwork;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();
        var access = string.Format("{0}:{1}", controller, action);
        if (unitofwork.UserRepository.AccessLevelRepository.ValidateAccess(userId, access))
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
    }
}
```

When I need to use the this Attribute it show me error

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAccess]
public async Task<ApiReturn> ChangeUserActiveStatus(long id)
{
    var result = await dispatchers.SendAsync(new UserActiveStateCommand { id = id });
    if (result.Success)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest(result.Exception);
}
```

And show this error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'unitofwork' of 'AllowAccessAttribute.AllowAccessAttribute(IDomainUnitOfWork, HttpContext)

**What's the problem? how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: I’ve generally preferred to keep my filters separate from the attribute for this reason. This pattern is described at https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/ along with its pros and cons.

Comment: @PranavNegandhi i need use shot sercuit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register the service in IoC container.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<IDomainUnitOfWork, DomainUnitOfWork>(); // per request injection
    ...
}
```

Try also changing the attribute of the method to `TypeFilter`:

```
[HttpGet]
[TypeFilter(typeof(AllowAccessAttribute))]
public async Task<ApiReturn> ChangeUserActiveStatus(long id)
```

Answer (score 1):

This blog has a more comprehensive answer: https://blog.iamdavidfrancis.com/posts/aspnet-filter-dependency-injection/

You can create your own custom filter and attribute like so and then use it as a method decorator in your controller:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string role)
        : base(typeof(CustomAuthorizeFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { role }
    }
}

public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string role;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(string role, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.role = role;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    ...
}
```

and then you can use it in your controller like so:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
        try{
            return Ok("Hello World");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
}
```